# How to capture screen shot with ExtJS button

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs

I have button named `printscreent` in `extjs` on click of which i need to capture the screen shot of the page.

I am not able find how to map the key event here. I am new to `extjs` please suggest something on it

I have tried `windows.print()` which opens the window to print the contents of the screen but i am looking for simple printscreen functionality

```
var printScrenButton = new Ext.create('Ext.form.button',{
    id:'printScrenButtonId',
    text:'Print Screen',
    width:50,
    handler: function() {

    }
});
```

Comment: can somebody please suggest something

Comment: Not posible per say, maybe take a look at something like http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html (Server side) or http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/ (Client side)